# How to remove item within Array Object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

Good morning guys, I'm new here and created this new topic because I have not found anything to take away my doubt.

I have the following situation.

I have an object:

```
var ITEMS = new Object ();
```

within this object have an array of phone numbers.

```
ITEMS.Phones = new Array ();
```

Add another object within that Array like below ...

```
var_number = $ ("# Number"). val ();
ITEMS.Phones.push (new Object ({phoneid: "", Number: var_number}));
```

Until then everything is ok, just can not delete an object of those within this array, I'm trying the following:

```
ITEMS.Phones.splice ($. InArray (removes ITEMS.Phones), 1);
```

But I am not getting success.

Does anyone know a way to solve my problem, or a simpler way to implement this?

Comment: What the hell sort of spaces did you put into this question?  Also, what does "Not getting success" mean?

Comment: Try posting actual code. It's very hard to read the pseudocode above. (If you think it's *actual* code, that would be the problem; it has at least one syntax error in the `splice` call.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's meant to be actual code rather than pseudocode, the line:

```
ITEMS.Phones.splice ($. InArray (removes ITEMS.Phones), 1);
```

...has at least one syntax error and one other error (`InArray` should be `inArray`). You're on the right track, in that `splice` does what you want.

You haven't said what `removes` is, but **if** it is a reference to an object you want to remove, then the line

```
ITEMS.Phones.splice ($.inArray(removes, ITEMS.Phones), 1);
```

...will remove it. But note that it must be a reference to the **same** object, because `inArray` uses `===` to search for the object. It can't be a reference to a different but equivalent object.

Suppose you want to remove the entry for the object that has a given `Number` property. You could do that like this:

```
var_number = /* ...the number you want to remove...*/
$.each(ITEMS.Phones, function(index, entry) {
    if (entry.Number === var_number) {
        ITEMS.Phones.splice(index, 1); // Removes the entry
        return false;                  // Terminates the $.each loop
    }
});
```

Comment: Bad nights sleep last night? ;)

Comment: @Liam: Oh dear, have I made some stoopid error above? *Edit*: Oh, you probably meant the opening sentence. Good point.

Comment: Nah, just pulling your chain. Seems like your being a bit harsh on the little fella. +1 btw!

Comment: @Liam: Yeah, that's what I meant. I changed the opening line, it was unnecessarily sarky. (I really am/was not sure that it was meant to really be code as opposed to pseudo code.) The good thing is that it seems to have helped the OP, so there we are. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your help, I managed to solve my problem with your help. sorry for the mistakes in question, and my first question on stack and how am Brazilian and not very well mastered English yet had to use google translator, once again thank you so much for your help.